# Scheduling job in APScheduler weekdays between 2 times

Tags: python, multithreading, triggers, cron, apscheduler

I want to schedule a job mon-fri, between two given times, say 10:20 to 18:35, for every 5 minute.
So it will run: 10:25, 10:30, 10:35, ..., 18:30, 18:35. every weekday.
I tried combining CronTrigger with IntervalTrigger but wasn't able to make it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using combining multiple `CronTrigger`s using an `OrTrigger`.

```
OrTrigger([
    CronTrigger(day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='10', minute='25-59/5'),
    CronTrigger(day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='11-17', minute='*/5'),
    CronTrigger(day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='18', minute='0-35/5')
])
```

The first `CronTrigger` is for the starting hour (i.e. 10), adjusted the minutes to run only from the 25th minute, every 5 minutes. The middle trigger runs every 5 minutes till the 17th hour. The last one is for the last hour, till the 35th minute.
This solution can be generalized to any start time, end time, and interval.